# I am trying to make a web-application using streamlit and getting error argument of type 'method' is not iterable

Tags: python, function, web-applications, streamlit, iterable

So I made a function which i later imported to another file no i am trying to make a web application using stream lit where I want user to upload a data and that data should go through my function and give me the output

This is my code

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from my_functions import backstack_2

st.title('Title')

uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("upload your data file",type = ["csv","tx"])

if uploaded_file is not None:
    data = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
    
    result = backstack_2(data)
    
    st.header('output')
    st.write(result)
```

Comment: Please provide the whole traceback

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, but since I do not have your "my_functions" module, I defined a dummy function instead.

```
def backstack_2(data):
    return data
```

This worked fine with me. So I guess, the problem does not lie in the shown code, but in how your module/function works. Maybe show a bit more of the traceback or the "backstack_2" function.

Comment: I tried doing this by making a new function in which it will read the data but still getting same error

My function

def read(data):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
    return(df)

the code

def read(data):
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
    return(df)